# Infinite stream from enumeration

Tags: java, functional-java

In functional-java, I expected the following to create an infinite stream:

```
Stream.forever(Enumerator.booleanEnumerator, false);
```

But it stops after one full enumeration. The javadoc kind of confirms this,  stating that it may only stream until the enumeration is exhausted.

```
Returns a stream that is either infinite or bounded up to the maximum 
value of the given iterator starting at the given value and stepping at 
increments of 1.
```

So, how do I make an infinite stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at [Stream.cycle](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/ce5db48c01cd53bc745e8ceb2e7cd4858dc4e39a/core/src/main/java/fj/data/Stream.java#L1652), it makes an infinite stream out of the input stream

```
Stream.cycle(Stream.forever(Enumerator.booleanEnumerator, false))
```

Comment: And there it is. Great. Though why not have `cycle(Enumeration)` in the API?